# on MacOS BigSur while adding iso file to Ubuntu VM in the virtualbox seeing error VM session was aborted. Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, unix, big-sur, virtualbox

My System information:
Macbook Pro macOS Big Sur
VirtualBox-6.1.22 version

What I'm trying to do ?

Trying to run Ubuntu 20.04 VM on top of VirtualBox-6.1.22 and while adding the Iso Image facing this issue VM session was aborted. Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), attaching a screenshot for the same

Tried the following so far but not helpful

Checked SIP status and it is enabled
(base) C02W82S8HV2R:~ jillasaikrishna$ csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.
(base) C02W82S8HV2R:~ jillasaikrishna$

Opened Terminal in Recovery and ran the following commands:
csrutil clear,
reboot

Then
Uninstalled and reinstalled VirtualBox.
went to System Preferences - Privacy - Allowed Oracle extension.

None of them helped, followed all the above steps as suggested here https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=98763&start=75#p488555  but I still stuck

[image]

Comment: What processor have you got - Intel or Apple Silicon

Answer (score 0):

Open the settings for your VM in the VirtualBox UI, go to Storage, click on the "empty" entry in the list of IDE Controllers, and select the disk icon over to the right of the screen. Finally, select to "Choose Virtual Optical Disk File", and select your .iso of choice. Then start the VM and it should boot just fine.

by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736495/virtualbox-windows-10-64-bit-host-the-vm-session-was-aborted

I hope it helps for your case too!